# EMI Shielding on PCB

Tags: rf, surface-mount, emc, emi-filtering

I'm thinking about replacing an 915MHz RF module on a PCB I designed with an equivalent circuit directly implemented on my PCB to overcome some supply chain issues. The module I'm replacing has an EMI shield covering it, so I'm thinking I should at least include provisions for an EMI shield on my PCB as well (i.e. at least a footprint). I went over to Digikey and I found [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/laird-technologies-emi/BMI-S-102/2175908) and [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/leader-tech-inc/SMS-201C/7203462) by way of parametric search and availability considerations.

[image] [image]

The main question that brings me here is the fact that there are these "vent holes" in the top of this EMI shield, whereas the module I'm replacing has no vent holes in the top. Will the vent holes compromise the effectiveness of the EMI shield? How significant of an effect is that?

A secondary, related question I have is whether an EMI shield like this can be included in an SMT assembly process as a component? Would it compromise the reflow of the parts under the EMI shield or does it have to be a added as second pass through the reflow oven?

Comment: Generally a hole that is < 1/4 wavelength in diameter is not significant and will work about as well as a solid conductor.  At 915 MHz your wavelength is 32 cm so these holes are well below the 8 cm 1/4 wavelength threshold.

Comment: Am I correct that I would want to connect the shield to GND in multiple places?

Comment: Yes, the more the better.